# Preloading Image so that it doesn't re-size during load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to, not sure if this is the right term, but preload it so that it's a set height and width when it's loaded.  I want it to be 100vh and 100vw.

On a side note, whats wrong with my jquery slideshow, I'm not great at jquery and javascript and attempted to get a slideshow going with setInterval.

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/ymfdn6hu/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    setInterval(function () {
      $('.featured-wrapper').addClass("slide-1").find('.city-sky').text(" City Sky");
      $('.featured-wrapper').addClass("slide-1").find('h3').text(" Interior Design |");
          $('.featured-wrapper').addClass("slide-1").find('.city-title').text("| Berlin");
         $('.featured-wrapper').removeClass("slide-2");
         $('.featured-wrapper').removeClass("slide-3");
    }, 4000);

        setInterval(function () {
      $('.featured-wrapper').addClass("slide-2").find('h3').text("changing");
      $('.featured-wrapper').removeClass("slide-1");
         $('.featured-wrapper').removeClass("slide-3");
     
    }, 8000);

            setInterval(function () {
      $('.featured-wrapper').addClass("slide-3").find('h3').text("changed");
      $('.featured-wrapper').removeClass("slide-1");
         $('.featured-wrapper').removeClass("slide-2");
     
    }, 12000);
  
    });
```

```css
.section-background-size{
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover !important;
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;
    transition:1s;
}
.section-one{
 background:$slide-2;
 height:100%;
     width: 33.333%;
 background-size:cover;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.featured-work{
 height:100vh;
 width:100vw;
 position:relative;

}
.featured-wrapper{
 background:url('http://coolvibe.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/vader-portrait1-992x558.jpg');
    @extend .section-background-size;

}
.slide-1{
   background:url('http://coolvibe.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/vader-portrait1-992x558.jpg') no-repeat;
@extend .section-background-size;
}
.slide-2{
background:url('http://i.imgur.com/o7ofCFF.jpg') no-repeat;
content:("test");
@extend .section-background-size;
}
.slide-3{
   background:url('http://coolvibe.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/star-wars-wallpapers1-992x558.jpg') no-repeat;
@extend .section-background-size;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="featured-work">
    <div class="featured-wrapper">
      <div class="article-title">
        <h2>PROJECTS</h2>
        <h3>Interior Design | </h3><span class="city-sky"> City Sky</span> <h3 class="city-title">| Berlin </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="view-projects">View Projects</div>
      <div class="language-change">
        <div class="lang english">English</div>
        <div class="lang">Chinese</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Regarding your side note: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers." (See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Just taking a quick look at your fiddle, I'm not sure what the problem is...

Answer (score 0):

There may be other ways to do this, but you can try loading the image using jQuery, and use the `load()` method's callback to let you know when it's loaded and fade it in (or display the entire page...)

Something like:

```js
$('#bigImg').load('file_with_img.html', function(){
    $('#overlay').fadeOut();
});
```

```css
#overlay{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;background:#333;z-index:1;}
#loadr{position:absolute;top:45%;left:45%;z-index:2;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="overlay"><img id="loadr" src="http://placeimg.com/100/100/aniamsl" /></div>
<div id="container">
 <div>This is the image we are waiting for:</div>
 <div id="bigImg"></div>
</div>
```

---

Reference:

http://api.jquery.com/load/